# How to show three rounded images in Collectionview cell in all iPhone screen sizes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview, screen-size

I have taken collectionview in storyboard and in its cell i have taken ImageView and its below one label

i need to show only three rounded images horzontally and number of rows from JSON vertically in all screen sizes

**like below image i need:**

in cell for imageview costraints like below

```
leading = trailing = top = bottom = 5
```

and in coding:

```
 class FriendsViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var galleryCollectionView: UICollectionView!

// MARK: - LifeCycleMethods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4
    let height = width*1.1
    
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    self.galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
 
}

}

class FriendsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageViewX!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
 imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.height/2.0    }
}
```

**so i am getting weird o/p in different screen sizes why?**

o/p of ipodtouch7

[image]

Comment: what if you put `imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.height/2.0` in `layoutSubviews()` instead of `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your collectionview cell Set constraints as shown in attached image, i.e. ur image view width should depend on imageview height, you can do it using ratio. [image]

Then in willDisplay method calculate cornerRadius

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    guard let cell = cell as? TestCollectionViewCell else
    {
        return
    }
    
     let cellHeight : CGFloat = cell.frame.size.height
    let labelHeight : CGFloat = cell.label?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cellHeight - labelHeight) / 2.0
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Below is the entire code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

{

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView : UICollectionView? = nil
let horizontalSpaceBetweenCell : CGFloat = 16
let verticalSpaceBetweenCell : CGFloat = 16
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup()
}

func setup()
{
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TestCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionViewCell")
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
    
   
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 40
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TestCollectionViewCell
    {
        return cell
    }
    
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    guard let cell = cell as? TestCollectionViewCell else
    {
        return
    }
    
    let cellHeight : CGFloat = cell.frame.size.height
    let labelHeight : CGFloat = cell.label?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cellHeight - labelHeight) / 2.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let numberOfCellsPerRow = 3
    let otherSpace = (edgeInsets.left + edgeInsets.right)
    let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - otherSpace) / CGFloat(numberOfCellsPerRow)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 80) // Height can be anything 80, 90 ,100
}
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 16
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return edgeInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    
}
```

}

Comment: i need to give label

Comment: how did you get the gaps b/w the circles

Comment: can you post your total code

Comment: @JsonSwift done - added label as well

Comment: if i give this line in "cellForItemAt"... `cell?.imgView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.size.height ?? 0 - 20) / 2.0` its not working.. could you explain me why?

Comment: if i give above mentiond line only in `willDisplay` working. why not in `cellForItemAt `.. any reason.. could you explan

Comment: @JsonSwift Because cell is not yet ready, so we don't know the size of the imageview, hence we can not calculate the radius. willDisplayCell gets called when your cell is ready, all constraints are set, and we get once last change to modify anything before it gets displayed. ---> But if you wan to do it in "cellForItemAt" then you will have to keep height of your cell need to be static i.e. fixed. then you already know what will be the height of ur imageview and then you can give static radius to imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Please change Widhth to height :
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.height/2.0

Comment: oops i have changed.. with that code only i am getting above o/ps

Comment: forgot to update in post.. i have changed with `imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.height/2.0` code only getting like that

Comment: ` mgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.width/2.0`  if its with `width` it looks tooo wierd